# How to mock two functions that are called from inside try/except block?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching, python-mock

I have a function foo which is something like this:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def foo(self, url):
        try:
            r = requests.get(url)
            buffer = StringIO.StringIO(r.content)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

I am trying to test it with Python mock library by doing something like this:

```
class FooTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_foo(self):
        obj = SomeClass()

        with patch('requests.get', MagicMock()):
            with patch('StringIO.StringIO', some_fake_method):
                obj.foo()
```

However, doing it this way would not patch any of them and I would instead get proper `response` and `StringIO` objects. If I omit `StringIO` from the patch, I get a `MagicMock` object as expected (instead of a `response` object). How do I make this work properly?

Comment: Try to change your approach https://github.com/dropbox/responses It could be easier.

Comment: Your patch is for `request.get`, not `requests.get` (although that should result in a different behavior than you report, so perhaps it's a typo in the question).

Comment: @chepner yeah that was a typo. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @MohammadRafayAleem I can't reproduce the issue you're seeing. Using nested `patch` with `'requests.get'` and `StringIO.StringIO` works fine for me. Can you provide a complete set of example code that reproduces it (meaning all we'd have to do is copy/paste then run it)?